# COUCHBASE-LITE-OSX + SQLCipher from CocoaPods

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoapods, couchbase, sqlcipher

Has anyone had success to install Couchbase-lite-osx + SQLCipher from CocoaPods?

```
pod 'couchbase-lite-osx', '~> 1.1.1'
pod 'SQLCipher', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Above lines install both libraries but couchbase encryption does not work.

Comment: Are you sure installation outside of CocoaPods is working? Maybe this framework does not work at all. If it installs, then it seems that not the installation is a problem here but the project itself. What you need to do?

Comment: Not sure. But they said on their wiki that it is possible (https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/wiki/Database-Encryption). I need to enable encryption for current couchbase based project .

Comment: This does not appear to be a problem connected with cocoapods at all. Cocoapods is just a tool to install the frameworks. It seems the framework does not work, but cocoapods installation is ok.